# tableview trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt crack in ios11

Tags: tableview, ios11

I Use trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt in IOS11 but when swipe multiple then app cracked.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, view, completionHandler in
      print("Deleting!")
      completionHandler(false)
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
  }
```

and some error

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UISwipeActionController swipeHandlerDidBeginSwipe:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/SwipeActions/UISwipeActionController.m:268
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No occurrence for index path (null)'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - look if you are doing something with your data (e.g. reloading) between your swipes.

---

I had similiar issue when I swipe-to-delete one cell (leaving it in edit mode - delete action visible) and then trying to swipe another caused that my app crashed. In my case it was because reloading table data in between those swipes.

Swipe-to-delete gesture calls `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` and `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` methods on `UITableViewDelegate` object. In the latter one I called `tableView.reloadData()`. When I swipe-to-delete other cell I got `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` method called for the first cell (also reloading data) and just after that system called `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` for the other cell and the data was out of sync and UIKit crashes.

When I removed the code that reloading data in `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` method my app won't crashes anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview).

As a minumum, return empty array, but not `nil`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    return []
}
```

Comment: It remove swipe functionality of tableview

Comment: FYI: I tried this, but it didn't solve my crasher. (I think there are several ways to trigger this problem, if I can narrow down a better description of my code path, I'll create a specific question and post it.)

Answer (score 0):

I just used UIViewController + UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate combination instead of using UITableViewController for the swiping issue.