# iOS 11 crash on swipe to delete - reason: No occurrence for index path (null)

Tags: ios, uitableview

My app is crashing on iOS 11 when I swipe to delete on a UITableViewCell:

```
2018-03-09 11:27:14.178099+0100 APP Dev[21820:47205020] *** Assertion failure in -[UISwipeActionController swipeHandlerDidBeginSwipe:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/SwipeActions/UISwipeActionController.m:268
2018-03-09 11:27:14.205179+0100 APP Dev[21820:47205020] void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 191] Exception handler
2018-03-09 11:27:14.209685+0100 APP Dev[21820:47205020] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No occurrence for index path (null)'
```

On iOS 10 the behavior is slightly different. The app does not crash but the delete button remains white and does not show (but the cell does slide).

I've never seen this before. Am I doing something wrong or is this an iOS bug?

**UPDATE:** I've just found out using tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: on iOS 10 that the indexPath returned is `{length = 2, path = 18446744073709551615 - 18446744073709551615}`. That's 2^64-1 so I guess there is an overflow happening somewhere. But why?

Comment: Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460022/tableview-trailingswipeactionsconfigurationforrowat-crack-in-ios11), seems like its Apple bug

Comment: @Tj3n I've read that before posting but I think it's not the same since they are reporting that everything is fine on iOS 10. Also please see my update to the question for some more information.