# Swipe for actions on UITableViewCells crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash, tableview

I'm building a UITableViewController, on iOS 11, using swift 4. I've implemented actions that appear when u swipe from right to left on a row. Here's the implementation:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Add") { (_, _, _) in }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

The problem is every time i swipe on a row, the app crashes. Here's some of the crash log:

> Assertion failure in -[UISwipeActionController swipeHandlerDidBeginSwipe:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/SwipeActions/UISwipeActionController.m:268
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No occurrence for index path (null)'

I've read a little around the internet about this problem, and it seems very popular, but i haven't any solutions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460022/tableview-trailingswipeactionsconfigurationforrowat-crack-in-ios11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not a great answer, but this is the only thing that worked for me. I used Objective-C files to configure my tableViewController and a bridging header, and it worked. So, for anyone who knows objective-c, and it actually is easy to work with once you learn swift, it's a great solution.

So, the problem is only occurring with swift.